# Equivalent of dup2 with windows socket in C

Tags: c, windows, sockets, redirect, dup2

I want to redirect my stdin, stdout and stderr through a socket.

This code works on Linux:

```
dup2(socket, 0);
dup2(socket, 1);
dup2(socket, 2);
```

but not on Windows because sockets aren't descriptors.

How can I do this in Windows?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a sifficient **specific** problem description. Read [ask], follow the advice and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf It doesn't work because there's no reason it should work. I think what s/he means is simply "what's the equivalent functionality on Windows?", not "I tried this and found a problem."

Comment: @immibis: Without the required information, how can we know? I'm no clairvoyant to know what someone thinks/means.

Comment: @Olaf I try to use dup2 like in Linux, he doesn't work because I'm working on windows. I didn't find the equivalent so I ask here if someone know the equivalent

Comment: @Olaf I reworded the question - better?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the return value of the Socket API is a `SOCKET`, which is not a file descriptor (or necessarily a small, non-negative integer).  It can, however, be used as a file handle in some ways, [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  In particular, you can use it with `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()`.

You could attempt to use the MS library function, `_open_osfhandle()`, to turn an OS level file handle into a C-style file descriptor.  This works with regular files but might or might not work on a `SOCKET`.  Once you have that file descriptor, you can pass it to `_dup2()`, with `_fileno(stderr)` as the second argument.  Be sure to close this descriptor with `_close()`, which will also close the original handle.

Comment: thanks but I tryed this http://pastebin.com/utXNQnym and he doesn't work

Comment: Remember to give `_dup2()` and `close()` the descriptor (`sck`) rather than the socket handle (`sock`).  Also, don't make two variables homonyms of each other.  Check your error codes, please?  It still might not work.

Comment: Oh yes, I fixed it. There are no error codes but my message isn't send. It didnt appear in console or in socket (I saw it with wireshark)

Comment: @Switch It seems as though this should either work or throw an error; if this isn’t a bug in your code, perhaps report it to MS as a bug in the system libraries.